# GPG decryption of encrypted files using node.js in cloud

Tags: node.js, gnupg

How to decrypt GPG encrypted file in cloud without saving private key in cloud using node.js

Moving from onPrem to Azure cloud. Currently for onPrem GPG vault is installed on the server, public/private keys are imported in GPG vault, decryption code uses fingerprint to decrypt files, but this means private key is physically present on the server. With moving to cloud, security team does not want to maintain private key on cloud PODS.
Going forward contents of the private key file will be available via an API call.
Tried decrypting an encrypted file by passing response object of private key API as 'recipient' and 'key' as arguments to cryptoReader.js which uses crpto, gpg modules to perform decryption. No luck.
If I try same code on the machine where private key is imported into GPG vault, it works.

Does this mean private key has to be physically imported into GPG vault on the server where decryption will be performed?
How do other security sensitive companies implement this in cloud?

```
//KeyBuffer contains contents of private key .asc file as response from API call

Decryption call:

stream.decryptFilewithPGP(<encryptedFileName>, { skipEmptyLines: true, encoding: 'utf8' },
 {
  mode: 'PGP',
  // key: keyBuffer,
  recipient: keyBuffer,
  passphrase: config.asymmetric.passphrase
  // fingerprint: config.asymmetric.fingerprint //for onPrem, for cloud no fingerprint
  });

Actual decryption implementation:
CryptoReader.prototype.decryptFilewithPGP = function (filepath, options, cipher) {
    var self = this;

    this._filepath = path.normalize(filepath);
    this._encoding = options && options.encoding || 'utf8';
    this._skipEmptyLines = options && options.skipEmptyLines || false;

    this._streamOptions = { encoding: this._encoding };

    if (options && options.start) {
        this._streamOptions.start = options.start;
    }

    if (options && options.end) {
        this._streamOptions.end = options.end;
    }
    let args = [
        '--passphrase', self.decode(cipher.passphrase),
        //'--recipient', cipher.key,
        '--recipient', cipher.recipient,
        '--trust-model', 'always',
        '--decrypt'
    ];

    console.log(`args: ${JSON.stringify(args)}`);

    readStream = this._readStream ? this._readStream : fs.createReadStream(this._filepath);
    outStream = this._outStream ? this._outStream : new Stream.PassThrough;
    //var outStream = new Stream.PassThrough;

    gpg.callStreaming(readStream, outStream, args, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            self.emit('error', err);
        }
        else {
            var _decData='', lastLine;
            outStream.on('data', function (data) {
                self._readStream.pause();
                self._outStream.pause();

                let _data = self._lineFragment.concat(data.toString('utf8'));
                self._lines = self._lines.concat(_data.split(/(?:\n|\r\n|\r)/g));
                self._lineFragment = self._lines.pop() || ''; //hold last line
                //console.log('data chunk size: ' + data.length + ' no. or rows: ' + self._lines.length);

                setImmediate(function () {
                    self._nextLine();
                });
            });
            outStream.on('end', function () {
                self._end = true;
                setImmediate(function () {
                    self._nextLine();
                });
            });
            outStream.on('error', function (error) {
                self.emit('error', err);
            });
        }
    });

    this._readStream = readStream;
    this._outStream = outStream;
};
```

Expected: Should decrypt encrypted file and return clear text (as is occurring in onPrem server or DEV machine which has private key imported)

Actual: No decryption is being performed.